# I need a confirmation of a successful PDO Connection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've read a lot of posts on this and there doesn't seem to be any consensus.  I'm writing an open source generic installer for web apps and I need to confirm a successful PDO connection.  It needs to test for a PDO connection and then it will write the actual config/init file. The file writing part works fine, but I can't seem to get a concrete verification that PDO is truly connected.  It says it's connected if the form is empty and it says it's connected if some of the info in the form is correct.  How do I get a clear indication that the pdo credentials are correct?  I'll give you a (stripped down) version of what I'm doing.

The form:

```
<H2>Please fill in your database credentials</H2>
<form class="form" action="" method="post">
  <label for="dbh">Database Host
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="dbh"  value="<?php if (!empty($_POST['dbh'])){ print $_POST['dbh']; } ?>"></label><br><br>

  <label for="dbu">Database User
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="dbu"  value="<?php if (!empty($_POST['dbu'])){ print $_POST['dbu']; } ?>"></label><br><br>

  <label for="dbp">Database Password
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="dbp"  value="<?php if (!empty($_POST['dbp'])){ print $_POST['dbp']; } ?>"></label><br><br>

  <label for="dbn">Database Name
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="dbn"  value="<?php if (!empty($_POST['dbn'])){ print $_POST['dbn']; } ?>"></label><br><br>
```

The PHP

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $dbh=$_POST['dbh']; //db host
    $dbu=$_POST['dbu']; //db username
    $dbp=$_POST['dbp']; //db password
    $dbn=$_POST['dbn']; //database name

    //If Testing
    if (!empty($_POST['test'])) {
        $dsn = "mysql:host=$dbh;dbname=$dbn;charset=utf8";
        $opt = array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
            );
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbu, $dbp, $opt);
     }

    //todo:  If Submitted, a bunch more logic here
}
?>
```

Comment: `$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbu, $dbp, $opt) or die('could not connect');` It will generate error if the connection is not established

Comment: I appreciate it... this only throws an error if the hostname is wrong.  If the username, db name, or password is wrong it doesn't throw an error. I think I'm going to try mysqli instead.

Comment: As I stated in the answer below, none of these answers include form validation.  In order for these checks to work a host, database, and user must be provided. If one of them is blank, the test will come back with a false positive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are any connection errors, a `PDOException` object will be thrown.

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbu, $dbp, $opt);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    // bad connection
}
```

To verify that data such as the host name, the database name and the login credentials are correct, you must force the user to not leave those data empty. In fact, it is entirely possible to establish a connection with just a host, that's because mysql allows the creation of accounts with blank username (empty string) that matches any username.

Also, in order to avoid parameter injection (example, a database name called `foo;port=123`) in the dsn string, you should at least check the presence of a semicolon or a `NULL` byte in the connection options (as host e database name).

Example

```
/**
 * Return a PDO object if the connection options are correct, and if the connection is established. False otherwhise.
 */
function test_mysql_connection($host, $dbname, $username, $password = null) {
    if (empty($host) || empty($dbname) || empty($username)) {
        // those parameters MUST NOT be empty
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Host, database name and username are required.')
    }

    try {
        $pdo = new PDO(build_mysql_dsn_safely($host, $dbname), $username, $password);
        return $pdo;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        // bad connection
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * See how is it parsed here: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/71c19800258ee3a9548af9a5e64ab0a62d1b1d8e/ext/pdo/pdo.c#L207
 */
function build_mysql_dsn_safely($host, $dbname = null, $charset = null, $port = null)
{
    static $bad_chars = array(';', '=', "\0");

    $vars = array_filter(array(
        'host' => $host,
        'dbname' => $dbname,
        'charset' => $charset,
        'port' => $port,
    ));

    foreach($vars as $param => $data) {
        foreach ($bad_chars as $bad_char) {
            if (strpos($data, $bad_char) !== false) {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
                    'Connection options "%s" contains an invalid value.', $param
                ));
            }
        }
    }

    return 'mysql:'.implode(';', array_map(function($optkey, $optval) {
        return $optkey.'='.$optval;
    }, array_keys($vars), $vars));
}

if($pdo = test_mysql_connection($_POST['dbh'], $_POST['dbu'], $_POST['dbn'], $_POST['dbp'])) {
    // connection established
}
```

Comment: I've seen a lot of people say not to do a try/catch and I need more than just a lack of errors.... I need an actual success message.

Comment: people that say to not catch exception? why? I've added an example.

Comment: @DanHoover You should absolutely use try-catch blocks. If you want the error message you can get it with `$e->getMessage()` in the catch block.

Comment: @DanHoover "I need an actual success message." There's no such thing. The manual [clearly states](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) a PDO object is returned on success and a [PDOException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php) is thrown if the attempt to connect to the requested database fails.

Comment: Yeah. The above answer doesn't work. If I leave all the fields blank it gives success.  If I put localhost (which is correct) and dsfds (which is wrong) in the user space, it gives success.  I think the best thing to do is to use mysqli for the configuration test.  PDO doesn't seem to work for this.

Comment: Note: This answer works, but in order for it to work as expected, you must force the user to enter a host, username, and database name. Failure to do so will result in false positives.  Thanks so much for helping me track this down.

Comment: you are right, I just tried. thanks for sharing. I've improved the answer

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I never even got to the point of doing form validation because I expected it to fail without a username or a proper db name.  Learn something new every day.  I appreciate your time.

Comment: @DanHoover, after I went to see the [php_pdo_parse_data_source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/71c19800258ee3a9548af9a5e64ab0a62d1b1d8e/ext/pdo/pdo.c#L207) function I've added a `build_mysql_dns_safely()` in the example.

Comment: You could add a `SELECT USER()` or something, and see if it errors.

Comment: I think that a `SELECT USER()` would only be useful to check if the connection is correctly established, and that is already guaranteed by the fact that the PDO object is created successfully.

Comment: I like that. Thank you!  I have little tests to test all sorts of possible system requirements and that one was bugging me!